# Execute an emacs command on a file from command line

Tags: command-line, emacs

There is an emacs plugin (https://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode) that is extremely useful. However, I'd like to make some of its functionality available for everyone (including us filthy vim users) and would like to write a wrapper to:

1. Use emacs to open the file
2. Execute the plugin command on the file
3. Save the file in place

Is there such a thing as emacs scripting? Where I can run something like:

emacs  file.v

And have it run without invoking the UI?

Thanks to the commenter for the answer. I've written the following lisp script:

```
(defun vexpand ()
  "run verilog-auto on all AUTO* blocks in file at fullpath FPATH ..."
  (let (mybuffer)
    (setq mybuffer (find-file (elt argv 1)))
    (verilog-auto)
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer mybuffer)))
(vexpand fpath)
```

But get:

```
Search failed: "\\<\\(end\\(?:c\\(?:lass\\|on\\(?:fig\\|nectmodule\\)\\)\\|interface\\|module\\|p\\(?:ackage\\|r\\(?:imitive\\|ogram\\)\\)\\)\\)\\>"
```

I suspect that it's not able to properly open the file as this invocation works if I manually open the file in emacs and evaluate the verilog-auto function.

Any ideas what could be wrong with the script above?

Comment: See the `--batch` option. You'll also need some intiialization code to load the plugin (see `--load`), another load for the file that will contain the function(s) that are going to be run and  some execution code to evaluate the functions that carry out the necessary operations (see `--eval`) . So the command will look something like this: `emacs --batch --load=plugin.el --load=my-funcs.el --eval=my-func file.v`.

Comment: @jkang, `Symbol’s function definition is void: fpath` is due to the final line call to `(vexpand fpath)`, as you haven't defined `fpath`.

Comment: You *might* find `--script` is what you want, rather than `--batch`.  It's a bit of reading, but I recommend going through https://lunaryorn.com/blog/emacs-script-pitfalls/ to get a good understanding of the (somewhat fiddly) way to put together a robust elisp script.

Comment: `--eval=vexpand` isn't valid, either.  That needs to be a lisp expression.  `--eval "(vexpand \"foo\")"` for instance.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I actually got to the point where it's running. But one of the search functions isn't working and returning the error I've edited the question to contain.

Comment: For your error, try adding `--eval "(setq debug-on-error t)"` to get a stack trace.  Presumably it's something in the depths of `(verilog-auto)`.

Comment: Found it. So verilog-auto does a lot of regex searches and the format of my file has it such that no search matched. This is showing up in the interactive session as well. I'll have to debug that.

I'll also likely have to make it so the script is more fault-tolerant. Thanks all!

Comment: If you think it will be reliable, `(ignore-errors (verilog-auto))` may be all that's needed.  That said, I wouldn't be particularly inclined to tell Emacs to automatically save the file after an editing operation errored out, so take care with that.

Comment: Ya I think I just want a more verbose (or useful) message rather than actually ignoring errors. I'll have to play around with how to print that.

Comment: If you want to handle specific errors, you can do that too.  You could handle any known safe cases, and then have a fallback which doesn't do anything destructive.  Read through `C-h i g (elisp)Handling Errors`.